# Domination in lebesgue convergence theorem

Tags: integration

Let $f: ]0; +\infty[ \to \mathbb{C}$ be such that $x \to \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}$ is integrable on $]0;+\infty[$.

Define, $I_{a,b} := \int_0^{\infty} f(x)\int_{[a;b]}sin(u)e^{-ux} du dx$ for $0<a<b$.
I already know that this double integral is well defined, and also that for any $x>0$, the interior integral in $u$ converges to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as $a\to 0$ and $b\to \infty$.
I would like to apply the dominated convergence theorem to claim that $I_{a,b} \to \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2} dx$ but I don't see easily how I should dominate the interior integral.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

First, the inner integral is given by

$$\int_a^b \sin(u)e^{-ux}\,dx=\frac{e^{-ax}(x\sin(a)+\cos(a))-e^{-bx}(x\sin(b)+\cos(b))}{1+x^2}$$

Then, note that we have for $a\ge 0$ and $x\ge 0$

$$e^{-ax}x\sin(a)\le\frac{ax}{1+ax}\le 1$$

Comment: Thx I get it now, the absolute value of the integral is less than $\frac{C}{1+x^2}$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  
Pleased to hear that this was useful.  And Happy Holidays.   -Mark